# How do I convert binary field to text in Ruby?

Tags: sql-server, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a MSSQL table with a field of type `image` that has some text stored in it.

The field has data that looks like this:

`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`

In PHP I can write a SQL query to convert that data like this: `SELECT CAST(CAST(CUST_ORDER_BINARY.BITS as VARBINARY(8000)) as VARCHAR(8000)) as result FROM CUST_ORDER_BINARY WHERE CUST_ORDER_ID = 'CO-299403S';`

When I try the same thing in Ruby I get a result like this:

`specs = VisualCustomer.connection.exec_query(sql).first`

`{"result"=>"T\u0000H\u0000I\u0000S\u0000 \u0000I\u0000S\u0000 \u0000A\u0000 \u0000L\u0000I\u0000G\u0000H\u0000T\u0000A\u0000R\u0000T\u0000 \u0000O\u0000R\u0000D\u0000E\u0000R\u0000.\u0000 \u0000 \u0000L\u0000I\u0000G\u0000H\u0000T\u0000A\u0000R\u0000T\u0000 \u0000I\u0000S\u0000 \u0000D\u0000O\u0000I\u0000N\u0000G\u0000 \u0000T\u0000H\u0000E\u0000 \u0000F\u0000A\u0000B\u0000.\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000L\u0000I\u0000G\u0000H\u0000T\u0000A\u0000R\u0000T\u0000 \u0000S\u0000H\u0000I\u0000P\u0000P\u0000I\u0000N\u0000G\u0000 \u0000T\u0000O\u0000 \u0000C\u0000U\u0000S\u0000T\u0000O\u0000M\u0000E\u0000R\u0000 \u0000<\u00008\u0000-\u00002\u00003\u0000-\u00001\u00007\u0000>\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000C\u0000o\u0000n\u0000n\u0000i\u0000e\u0000,\u0000 \u0000p\u0000l\u0000e\u0000a\u0000s\u0000e\u0000 \u0000p\u0000r\u0000i\u0000n\u0000t\u0000 \u0000s\u0000t\u0000i\u0000c\u0000k\u0000e\u0000r\u0000s\u0000 \u0000f\u0000o\u0000r\u0000 \u0000e\u0000a\u0000c\u0000h\u0000 \u0000o\u0000u\u0000t\u0000e\u0000r\u0000 \u0000b\u0000o\u0000x\u0000 \u0000t\u0000h\u0000a\u0000t\u0000 \u0000i\u0000n\u0000c\u0000l\u0000u\u0000d\u0000e\u0000s\u0000 \u0000t\u0000h\u0000e\u0000 \u0000i\u0000n\u0000f\u0000o\u0000:\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000(\u00001\u0000)\u0000 \u0000o\u0000f\u0000 \u0000(\u00001\u0000)\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000L\u0000A\u00002\u0000 \u0000T\u0000h\u0000r\u0000e\u0000e\u0000 \u0000L\u0000a\u0000r\u0000g\u0000e\u0000 \u0000\r\u0000\n\u00008\u00006\u0000\\\u0000\"\u0000L\u0000 \u0000x\u0000 \u00006\u0000\\\u0000\"\u0000W\u0000 \u0000x\u0000 \u00008\u0000\\\u0000\"\u0000H\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000N\u0000a\u0000t\u0000u\u0000r\u0000a\u0000l\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000P\u00002\u00000\u00009\u00008\u00001\u00000\u00005\u0000 \u0000M\u0000O\u0000D\u0000 \u0000P\u0000i\u0000z\u0000z\u0000a\u0000 \u0000S\u0000u\u0000g\u0000a\u0000r\u0000h\u0000o\u0000u\u0000s\u0000e\u0000,\u0000 \u0000U\u0000T\u0000"}`

So the data is "almost" there. :)

I've tried gsubing to remove the `\u0000` from the result but that's not working, obviously.

** EDIT 1 **

So, for some reason, getting the data from MSSQL into ruby is causing some kind of partial translation. I never get the raw data from the field, instead I get the "semi-translated" data. Even if I just query it, it still comes out like

`"T\x00H\x00I\x00S\x00 \x00I\x00S\x00 \x00A\x00...`

I tried to put it back doing:

`s = order_specs.each_byte.map { |b| b.to_s(16) }.join`

Then, when I do:

`order_specs = s.scan(/.{2}(?=0{2})/).map{|s| s.to_i(16)}.pack("c*").tr("\x02", " ")`

I just get an empty string. :/

Comment: have you tried to write this image to a file?

Comment: Slight detour...the image datatype has been deprecated in favor of varbinary(max) for over a decade now. Probably time to stop using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out. I needed to do `string.gsub("\u0000", '')`

So, I was getting the data from the MSSQL database correctly it seemed, but I that null byte was really throwing things off and was being sent to the front end where it was appearing on the page. i swear i tried gsubing before but for whatever reason it wasn't working. I tried it again now before when the response is being formed and it is now being sent correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "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"
```

**Code**:

```
puts s.scan(/.{2}(?=0{2})/).map{|s| s.to_i(16)}.pack("c*")
```

**Output**:

```
THISISALIGHTARTORDER.LIGHTARTISDOINGTHEFAB.
LIGHTARTSHIINGTOCUSTOMER<8-23-17>

Connie,leaserintstickersforeachouterboxthatincludestheinfo:
(1)of(1)
LA2ThreeLarge
86\"Lx6\"Wx8\"H
Natural
29815MODizzaSugarhouse,UT
```

Note: Some characters are unprintable, so they do not appear in this page. See the edit page of this answer for detail.

Or, if you replace `"\x02"` with a space,

```
puts s.scan(/.{2}(?=0{2})/).map{|s| s.to_i(16)}.pack("c*").tr("\x02", " ")
```

you get:

```
THIS IS A LIGHTART ORDER.  LIGHTART IS DOING THE FAB.
LIGHTART SHIING TO CUSTOMER <8-23-17>

Connie, lease rint stickers for each outer box that includes the info:
(1) of (1)
LA2 Three Large 
86\"L x 6\"W x 8\"H
Natural
29815 MOD izza Sugarhouse, UT
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens when you're inspecting the data, but when you write it will be fine:

Example:

```
$ ruby -e 'bin = File.read("/bin/ls");p bin; File.open("/tmp/file","w+"){|f| f.write bin}'
"\u007FELF\u0002\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000 ...
....
$ md5sum /bin/ls
84b7b042405dfc79f2afe9b12d6b931d  /bin/ls
$ md5sum /tmp/file
84b7b042405dfc79f2afe9b12d6b931d  /tmp/file
```

So here we read a binary file `/bin/ls` and wrote it to another file `/tmp/file` as you can the the checksums are the identical.

Comment: I noticed that if i just type the variable in irb then it shows the hidden characters, but if i "put" the variable on the screen then it doesn't.

Comment: However, if I return the variable from my rails backend to the angular2 frontend those characters remain. :/ How can I remove them from being sent via the backend?